# Autofill input text on Sharepoint 2007 using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

im sure this is a simple question but can't understand why this isn't working. I simply want to set the current time automatically to an input field. I am using Jquery at the moment to accomplish the task. I know jquery works because if I do alert (time); it shows me the time as expected.

Just to add, I set the jquery script in a text then referenced into a Content Editor Webpart under the list.

Below is the HTML of my input generated by Sharepoint. I decided to target the title as its the only consisting attribute in there.

```
<input type="text" class="ms-long" title="Current time" id="ctl00_m_g_dd7a368d_cc10_4464_a245_c7fc87ae6650_ff2_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" maxlength="255" name="ctl00$m$g_dd7a368d_cc10_4464_a245_c7fc87ae6650$ff2_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField">
```

Below is the Jquery script I am trying to run. A the moment this script does nothing to my input text box.

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var time = (dNow.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dNow.getDate() + '/' + dNow.getFullYear() + ' ' + dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes();
    $("input[Title='Current time']").val(time);
    });
    </script>
```

Any help would appreciated on this.

Comment: Where is `dNow` defined?

Comment: Yeah might of missed that, but the problem is still there even if I set a static value in the .val for example `$("input[Title='Current time']").val("test");` still returns blank in my input when I load my page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it works fine if you define the dNow first: tested on Chrome and Opera

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var dNow = new Date();
    var time = (dNow.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dNow.getDate() + '/' + dNow.getFullYear() + ' ' + dNow.getHours() + ':' + dNow.getMinutes();
    alert(time);
    $("input[title='Current time']").val(time);
 });
```

If that's not working for you, you have some other problem in your JavaScript, debug and check for other errors

Comment: Oh wow defining the variable fixed it, that was probably the problem this whole time and was looking else where. Thanks you very much.